# How to create selection field in odoo 9

Tags: odoo, xml-rpc, odoo-9

i want to make selection and shows different fields.

ex: 
i choose test1 show field 1,test2 show field 2, and test 3 show field 3.

this is my class

```
class topo_log(models.Model):
_name = 'topo.log'
selection_type  = fields.Selection(string='Selection Type', selection=[('test1','Test 1'), ('test2','Test 2'), ('test3','Test 3')])
testfield1      = fields.Many2one('test.model1',string='Test 1', select=True)
testfield2      = fields.Many2one('test.model2',string='Test 2', select=True)
testfield3      = fields.Many2one('test.model3',string='Test 3', select=True)
```

and this is my xml

```
<field name="selection_type" />
<field name="testfield1" attrs="{'invisible':[('selection_type','==','test2','test3')]}" />
<field name="testfield2" attrs="{'invisible':[('selection_type','==','test1','test3')]}" />
<field name="testfield3" attrs="{'invisible':[('selection_type','==','test1','test2')]}" />
```

but, my code didn't work. anyone can help my code?

Answer (score 1):

Change your filter domain like this

```
<field name="testfield1" attrs="{'invisible':[('selection_type','in',['test2','test3'])]}" />
```